# Saving result to text file

Tags: php, file

I've searched around this site for an answer but couldn't find any help in my problem.
I have a script with a form and I'd like to get the contents of the input written into a txt file (line by line in mytext.txt file for example) when the submit button is pressed - or maybe simpler only the result.

Result / content of "echo $result['text'];" should be saved to text file (mytext.txt)

I tried to add something like that after each "echo" but it doesn't work. here is the sample code.

```
$f = fopen("mytext.txt", "w");
fwrite($f,  $result);
fclose($f);
```

or

```
$f = fopen("mytext.txt", "w");
fwrite($f,  $username);
fclose($f);
```

or

```
$txt = "$result";
$myfile = file_put_contents('mytext.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

but still no luck. 
How can I do that and where to add it? With PHP or maybe with JavaScript? Help please.

***edit***: 
PART of the script (I'm sorry I forgot about it)

```
<?php

if(count($check_ex) == 2){
    $ex_name = $check_ex[0]."_".$check_ex[1];
}else{
    $ex_name = $check_ex[0];
}
            $additional_button = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='submitform_$dom_$ex_name()' ><button id='buy' class='btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right order-btn'>".__($additional_button_name, 'kate')."</button></a>";
        }elseif($integration == 'woocommerce'){
            if($show_price){
                $show_price = '- '.kate_display_price($username).__('/year','kate');
            }
            $additional_button = "<a href='?&add-to-cart=$additional_button_link&username=$username' id='buy' class='btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right order-btn' $buy_new_tab >".__($additional_button_name,'kate')." $show_price</a>";
            }elseif($integration == 'custom'){
            if(!$additional_button_name == '' AND !$additional_button_link == ''){
                $additional_button_links = str_replace( '{username}', $username, $additional_button_link );
                $additional_button = "<a id='buy' class='btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right order-btn' href='$additional_button_links' $buy_new_tab >".__($additional_button_name,'kate')."</a>";
            }else{
                $additional_button = '';
            }
        }else{
            $additional_button = '';
        }

        $custom_not_found_result_text = str_replace( '{username}', $username, $custom_not_found_result_texts );
        $whmcs = "<script type='text/javascript'>
                function submitform_$dom_$ex_name()
                {
                  document.whmcs_$dom_$ex_name.submit();
                }
                </script>
                <form method='post' name='whmcs_$dom_$ex_name' id='whmcs' action='$additional_button_link/cart.php?a=add&username=register' $buy_new_tab>
                <input type='hidden' name='usernames[]' value='$username' >
                <input type='hidden' name='usernamesregperiod[$username]' value='1'>
                </form>";
        if ($available->status == 1) {
                $result = array('status'=>1,
                                'username'=>$username, 
                                'text'=>    '<div class="callout callout-success alert-success clearfix available">
                                            <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left:1px;text-align:left;">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="margin-right:1px;"></i> '.__($custom_found_result_text,'kate').' </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right:1px">'.__($additional_button,'kate').' '.$whmcs.'</div>
                                            </div>
                                            '); 
                echo $result['text'];



        } elseif($available->status == 0) {
                $result = array('status'=>0,
                                'username'=>$username, 
                                'text'=>    '<div class="callout callout-danger alert-danger clearfix not-available">
                                            <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left:1px;text-align:left;">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="margin-right:1px;"></i> '.__($custom_not_found_result_text, 'kate').' 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right:1px">'.$www_link.'</div>
                                            </div>
                                            ');
                echo $result['text'];


        }elseif ($available->status == 2) {
                $result = array('status'=>2,
                                'username'=> $username, 
                                'text'=>    '<div class="callout callout-warning alert-warning clearfix notfound">
                                            <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left:1px;text-align:left;">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="margin-right:1px;"></i> '.__('not found','kate').' 
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            ');
                echo $result['text'];


        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Please enter the username';
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it doesn't work? i think your first two codes work

Comment: Is the path to text file in same directory as the php file?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for the file in the correct directory? Try using an absolute pathname so you can be sure it's writing to the directory you want. And make sure that the user running the script has permission to create files in that directory.

Comment: What does this have to do with Javascript?

Comment: Btw, `file_put_contents` will return the number of bytes written, and not a pointer to that file. Here is the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: I edited my post , I'm sorry I forgot to add. Script has permission to create files in that directory, I am testing it on localhost (xampp with apache2 & php7).  Where can I add this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having errors when trying to get this code to run, check that you have granted your PHP file access to write information to the hard drive.

Comment: On Unix and Windows, permissions are granted to users, not individual files.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the directory you're trying to save your txt file is writable.
Example:

```
$contents = 'Here goes your content';
$dirName = __DIR__; //in case you're saving in another directory, you may use 'files/directory/' instead of __DIR__
$fileName = $dirName.'/mytext.txt';

if (!is_writable($dirName)) {
    throw new \Exception("This folder is not writable: '$dirName'");
}

//Checks if the content was added
if (!file_put_contents($fileName, $contents)) {
    throw new \Exception("Could not write to file: $fileName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, it may be that the directory does not have permission to create files.